# MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone

is MPMoviePlayerController only use to play ipod music ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name indicates, it can play any media file that an iPod can play, including movies and music files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at Apple reference docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and of course have a look at the multimedia programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767

Bye!